# typename keyword for std::function

Tags: c++, templates, std-function, typename

I have a class

```
class Consumer
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void()> EventHandler;
    ...
};
```

which I would like to use in this as template

```
template<class Consumer>
class ConsumerGroup
{
public:
    typename Consumer::EventHandler EventHandler;
    ConsumerGroup(EventHandler handler);
};
```

But above one results compilation error saying EventHandler is not a type.
How should I use typename keyword in this case?

Comment: `std::function` was introduced in c++11. So this question can't be about c++98.

Comment: `typename Consumer::EventHandler EventHandler;` define a member variable, not a type.

Comment: @NathanOliver I would have removed the tag myself, but OP explicitly added the requirement in an edit after the original post. This is an inconsistency that deserves the be addressed by OP.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Maybe that we already are in a (not shown) custom namespace, alllowing to be in C++98 ;-)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Meh.  This way the Q is more generic and the answers give the OP a C++98 version if they really need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a type alias for dependent `Consumer::EventHandler`.

This should work:

```
using EventHandler =  typename Consumer::EventHandler;
```

for lower compiler versions(before C++11)

```
typedef  typename Consumer::EventHandler EventHandler;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `typename` keyword isn't used to import or define new type-aliases. What you're doing is really defining a *member variable* named `EventHandler`.

You need to use `typdef` again to define a type-alias:

```
typedef typename Consumer::EventHandler EventHandler;
```

Or with modern C++ using `using`:

```
using EventHandler = typename Consumer::EventHandler;
```